# JSON results in API calls

Tags: python, json

If I go about `last.fm API`, using `pylast` wrapper, and lookup for `similar tracks`, like so:

```
track = last.get_track('Radiohead', 'Karma Police')
    for similar in track.get_similar():
        print (similar)
```

I get:

```
SimilarItem(item=pylast.Track(u'Radiohead', u'No Surprises', pylast.LastFMNetwork('key', 'secret', 'string', 'user', 'string2')), match=1.0)
SimilarItem(item=pylast.Track(u'Radiohead', u'Paranoid Android', pylast.LastFMNetwork('key', 'secret', 'string', 'user', 'string2')), match=0.995)
```

if I try to index it:

```
track = last.get_track('Radiohead', 'Karma Police')
    for similar in track.get_similar():
        print (similar[0])
```

I get:

```
Radiohead - No Surprises
Radiohead - Paranoid Android
```

I would like to print `similar` in this fashion:

```
         {
         "artist": "Radiohead",
         "track":"No surprises"
         },
         {
         "artist": "Radiohead",
         "track":"No surprises"
        }
```

but If I try `similar[0][0]`, I get the following error:

`TypeError: 'Track' object does not support indexing`

How do I structure the result as a `dictionary`, then?

Comment: That library looks to return full Python classes, not JSON

Comment: @cricket_007, yeah, but is there a workaround with `import json` and use to load the data?

Comment: you need a mapper to convert an object to a json

Comment: Why do you want the data in json format? Presumably, pylast just converted the json into something more manageable. If you want the pure json from the API request, just don't use pylast.

Comment: @Evert I've edited the question. A `dictionary` would suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a dictionary you can do it this way:

```
track = last.get_track('Radiohead', 'Karma Police')
d = dict(str(item[0]).split(" - ") for item in track.get_similar())
```

Comment: do you mean `d = dict(item[0].split(" - ") for item in track.get_similar())`?

Comment: yeah) it what i meant

Comment: I get `AttributeError: 'Track' object has no attribute 'split'`

Comment: so it's not a string you getting back when print? what is it ?

Comment: i updated the answer though, it had some issue, did you get the error after or before the update?

Comment: after, I'm afraid...I get no string, apparently, but `Radiohead - No Surprises
Radiohead - Paranoid Android` on command line, like I said above

Comment: can you give me import part of your script?

Comment: `import requests
import string
import pylast
import json
from itertools import islice` but only `pylast` being used in this case

Comment: what is last in this case?

Comment: i figured it out but i don't have api key and credentials to proceed

Comment: this api requires credentials to connect which i don't have

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126283/discussion-between-data-garden-and-tinysandy).